# django's DateField model field and acceptable values

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm having a bit of trouble with django's DateField model field.  Shouldn't it be able to accept `fiveDaysLater` as a valid date object?  When I try to add fiveDaysLater into the database, I get an error saying `cannot add null value to date`.  However, the second I change the `date` field to a regular `CharField`, the fiveDaysLater value is added to the database with no problem.  fyi if I print fiveDaysLater, I get `2011-09-28`

My view:

```
def myView():
    now = datetime.date.today()
    fiveDaysLater = now + datetime.timedelta(days=5)
    newDate = Speech(date = fiveDaysLater)
    newDate.save()
```

My model

```
class Speech(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me, barring the typo in the view definition (missing parens).  What database and version of django?  Perhaps you've left something important out in simplifying your code to share?

Comment: is your error coming from `fiveDaysLater = now + datetime.timedelta(days=5)` or from the `save()`?

Comment: I'm using sqlite with django version 1.3.  The error is coming from newDate.save() because `fiveDaysLater = now + datetime.timedelta(days=5)` prints 2011-09-28.

Answer (score 0):

"However, the second I change the date field to a regular CharField..." Just a suspicion but if you made this change in your code, make sure to delete and recreated the Speech table using syncdb, otherwise, sqlite will not be aware of this change. (or you could change the datatype using sqlite exporer for firefox or something like that...)